# C# Setting Button URL Direct At Runtime

Tags: c#, url, button, configuration, runtime

I have a program I created which amongst other things has 20+ buttons which link to various sites and programs I use for work. The program has started being used by other people and the buttons don't quite meet their need.

What I would like to do is allow the user to set the button up to direct to a specified URL at runtime, and maintain that information for future use (I'll work on that bit later) - Allowing every user to cater it to their own criteria.

To make this easier, the buttons already exist with a generic name, and no text, and are initially invisible. All of them when in use would direct to a particular URL, nothing else. I would like the user to be able to click an "Add" button, set the button Text, text colour (I can do this bit) and fill in a text box to set the url for the browser (Default browser, not webBrowser.), which they would save, making the button visible, and usable.

I've had a look around, but cannot for the life of me work out how to do this.

Some guidance on the issue would be fantastic

Thanks in advance

Anthony

Comment: Are you looking for this to persist when the application quits?

Comment: @BrandonScott Ideally yes - but I was planning to take baby steps. Get it working, then work on saving the information once the app is closed. 

Upon thinking about it - I think I could set the button command as a variable, let the user set the variable as a url, and set the other values as needed. And just make the next blank button visible when the previous one has been configured correctly, and keep doing that until all are taken up. 

I think that will work, but I suppose I was hoping for a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using a `DataGridView` with a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

Because I had a set number of available buttons, I was able to create them and hide them. Set it up so the user sets the variable that the Start.Process. is using for the url, as well as set the button text in real time.

They save this information in a text document that's stored in the programs home folder, and this is pulled back through when the program is re-opened. This will work well for my simple purposes.